# Free Components of the Riemann Tensor

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

Knowing the symmetries of the Riemann tensor, it is known that in 4-dimensional space we would have only 20 free components. My question is: How one can decide which components are necessary to calculate in a practical way?

I am trying to list every single component and use the symmetries to eliminate the ones that are related to make sure that I am not forgetting anyone but it doesn't seem efficient at all.

Comment: This is a very problem specific question. If your spacetime has any symmetries then there are usually tricks you can do to save time. For a general spacetime though, there really isn't any time saving technique, you just have to turn the crank.